# Combine rectangle split with array

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrays, hline

I want to draw a "complicated" figure, like shown below.

What is need to be done:

1. Enlarge the `\hdashline` to fit the hole width (drawn in red)
2. Remove the dashed line (`:`) from the first row (done per hand)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2, draw, inner sep=+0pt] {
$\begin{array}{l|l|l}
n & loooooooooooooong & m\\
\end{array}$
\nodepart{two}
$\begin{array}{l@{{}={}}l:l@{{}={}}l}
a & 0  & b & 0\\
\hdashline
c & 0 & d & 0\\
\end{array}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Update:

This should also work, if the second array contains more than two rows (e. g. 3 or 4)

What is need to be done:

1. Remove the dashed line (`:`) from the first row (green rectangle in upper figure)
2. Somehow the `\draw[dashed,green]` and `\hline` don't have exactly the same y-coordinate
3. Somehow the helpers add whitespace
4. Replace the hardcoded line width

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,calc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (n) [rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2, draw, inner sep=+0pt] {
$\begin{array}{l|l|l}
n & loooooooooooooong & m\\
\end{array}$
\nodepart{two}
$\begin{array}{l@{{}={}}l:l@{{}={}}l}
a & 0  & b & 0\\
\hline %only for position control
c & 0 & d & 0\\
c & 0 & d & 0\\
c & 0 & d & 0\\
\end{array}$};

%helper
\node[inner sep=0] (two north west) at ($(n.text split west)-(0,0.2pt)$) {}; %hardcoded
\node[inner sep=0] (two south west) at ($(n.south west)+(0,0.4pt)$) {}; %hardcoded
\node[inner sep=0] (two north east) at ($(n.text split east)-(0,0.2pt)$) {}; %hardcoded
\node[inner sep=0] (two south east) at ($(n.south east)+(0,0.4pt)$) {}; %hardcoded

\draw[dashed,green] ($(two south west)!0.75!(two north west)$) -- ($(two south east)!0.75!(two north east)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I use the helpers, because `a!0.75!b+c` seems to be interpreted as `(a!0.75!b)+c` and I'm not able to do something like `a!0.75!(b+c)`

Comment: `a!0.75!(b+c)` should be doable as `($(a)!0.75!($(b)+(c)$)$)`. The hardcoded shifts seem to coincide with `\pgflinewidth` and `\pgflinewidth/2`, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (n) [rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2, draw,
           inner ysep=0pt] {
$    \begin{array}{ c|c|c }
n & loooooooooooooong & m\\
     \end{array}$
\nodepart{two}
$    \begin{array}{ r:l }
a = 0   & b = 0\\
c = 0   & d = 0\\
\end{array}$
    };
\draw[dashed] (n.two west) -- (n.two east); % <-- horizontal dashed line
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:**
i'm still not sure how your table should looks. now, after edited your question, i guessing, that your table in second part of node can has any number of lines and you like to have aligned equations in rows at sign `=`. for example like this:

[image]

in this case my first suggestion doesn't gives desired result. in it you need to make the following changes:

- use `tabularx` environment instead `array`
- for aligning of equations at sign˙=`the`tabularx` need four columns
- define width of node

  ```
  \documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
  \usepackage{tabularx}
  \usepackage{arydshln}
  \newlength\tabwidth     % for defining node width

  \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
  \settowidth\tabwidth{$\begin{array}{l|l|l}      % calculating node width
                          n & loooooooooooooong & m\\
                        \end{array}$}
  \node (n) [rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2, draw, inner sep=0pt] {
  $\begin{array}{l|l|l}
  n & loooooooooooooong & m\\
  \end{array}$
  \nodepart{two}
  \begin{tabularx}{\tabwidth}{@{}                 % table width is equal to node width
      >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash $}X<{$}@{$\,=\,$}
      >{\raggedright\arraybackslash$}X<{$}:
      >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash $}X<{$}@{$\,=\,$}
      >{\raggedright\arraybackslash$}X<{$}
                               @{}}
      a & 0 & b & 1234\\
      \hdashline
    abc & 0 & d & 0\\
      \hdashline
   abcd & 0 & d & 0\\
      \hdashline
      c & 0 & d & 0\\
  \end{tabularx}
      };
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: can you please explain `(n.two west) -- (n.two east)`. Isn't it supposed to be `to` instead of `two`.

Comment: @subhamsoni see page 796 of the [documentation](https://mirror.informatik.hs-fulda.de/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). `two` refers to the second part

Comment: @zarko well, this doesn't work, if the (second) array has more than two rows, does it? Or is it possible to correct this with a yshift? Btw, you missed the part of removing the dashed line between `a` and `b`

Comment: (The `l@{{}={}}l:l@{{}={}}l` is there with purpose, to align the equations above and below the dashed line. if this is possible by something else, there might be a hole other solution (but the alignment is irrelevant for your solution.)) Is there a difference between `0pt` and `+0pt`? I found `+0pt` in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130119/110154)

Comment: @Ben, my solution is tested (twice) and it works!i haven't any idea how you use it. zero is zero. i do not know for positive or negative zero, why Qrrbrbirlbel use this notation, i don't know. you should ask him. however, even use his notation my example, it works.

Comment: @Zarko please see my update

Comment: @Ben, please see addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment but it is too long for a comment. One can draw the lines without hardcoded distances.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,calc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (n) [rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2, draw, inner sep=+0pt] {
$\begin{array}{l|l|l}
n & loooooooooooooong & m\\
\end{array}$
\nodepart{two}
$\begin{array}{l@{{}={}}l:l@{{}={}}l}
a & 0  & b & 0\\
\hline %only for position control
c & 0 & d & 0\\
c & 0 & d & 0\\
c & 0 & d & 0\\
\end{array}$};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NumRows}{4}
\foreach \X in {1,...,\numexpr\NumRows-1} % \numexpr trick from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/477077/121799
{\coordinate (aux-\X) at ($(n.text split)!\X/\NumRows!(n.south)$);
\draw [blue,dashed] (aux-\X-|n.west) -- (aux-\X-|n.east);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]